# "should They?" or "should they be?"?

Tags: grammaticality, semantic-roles

> 1. They believe this.
>      Should they?
> 2. They are taken as believing this. 
>      **Should they?**

While (1) sounds fine, something seems to be off with (2). Shouldn't it be "should they be?" in (2)? Is "should they" grammatical in (2)? Even if it is grammatically sound, is there something semantically off in (2) when compared with (1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in thinking that you need to add **be** to the second sentence in the second example.

The reason you need the *be* is because the second example uses an auxiliary verb in its construction. That construction needs to be paralleled in its question form.

This could also be considered an elliptical sentence where part of it has been omitted but understood to exist.

Here is a version of the sentence, where the omitted information is shown in parentheses. It clearly shows the parallelism:

> They **are taken** as believing this. Should they **be** (**taken** as believing this)?

And the shortened version:

> They **are** *taken* as believing this. Should they **be**?

Comment: Thanks. For the sake of more clarity, I am going to ask the second question separately. Perhaps it is a good idea that you cut the second part of your answer and pasted it in answer to my next question.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/194343/should-vs-shouldnt

Comment: As I has changed the question, the second part of your answer is no longer necessary. Would you please edit it?

Comment: @user204489 Done.  I updated the first part to make it more complete.